# How do I add the functions

Tags: python, python-2.7

how do i add function to this? Since we are learning about function in this chapter it is important for me to implement one for this program.This is my code so far:
    scores = []

```
def print_scores(copy_scores):
   for i in range(len(copy_scores)):
       print (copy_scores[i],)

scores = [75, 84, 66, 99, 51, 65]
print_scores (scores)
print ()

while True:
   scores = int(input("Please enter your score values"))
if scores == -99:
    break

Sample output:
75, 84, 66, 99, 51, 65
 P   P   P   P   F   P
```

Comment: You need to be specific about the problems you're having implementing the functions.

Comment: how do I print the score along with whether the user passed or fail using functions?

Comment: Hint: Use `scores.append()` to add something to the `scores` list. Don't replace the list variable when you read the input. And make sure you get the indentation right.

Comment: You use use an `if` statement to decide if the score is above the passing grade.

Comment: you shouldn't have both python-2.7 and python-3.x tags, there are enough differences that you can't use the same answer for both. Your `input()` syntax is 3.x, your `print` is 2.7.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: The sample output doesn't match the instructions..shouldn't `51` also be a `P` since it is more than `50`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scores = []
grades = []

def print_scores(copy_scores):
    print(', '.join(str(score) for score in copy_scores))

def find_min_odd(scores_list):
    if not scores_list:
        return []
    if scores_list[0] % 2 == 1:
        return [scores_list[0]] + find_min_odd(scores_list[1:])
    return find_min_odd(scores_list[1:])



def set_grades(scores_list):
    for score in scores_list:
        if score >= 50:
            grades.append('P')
        elif score < 50:
            grades.append('F')

print(''.join(str(grade) for grade in grades))

while True:
    user_input = input("Please enter your score value: ")
    if int(user_input) == -99:
        break
    scores.append(int(user_input))

print_scores(scores)
set_grades(scores)

print(', '.join(grade for grade in grades))
print('minimum odd score:', min(find_min_odd(scores)))
```

Demo:

```
Please enter your score value: 75
Please enter your score value: 84
Please enter your score value: 66
Please enter your score value: 99
Please enter your score value: 51
Please enter your score value: 65
Please enter your score value: -99
75, 84, 66, 99, 51, 65
P, P, P, P, P, P
minimum odd score: 51
```

Comment: oh i missed that detail, smallest odd number. ok that should be easy, one min.

Comment: ok updated to find minimum odd score.

Comment: Sure, maybe I can help. I guess it depends on the kind of problem though.

Comment: Since this question is closed, do you want to discuss the new problem in a chat room?

Comment: can you join this chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149650/sumena-dahal

Comment: Ok sorry about that, maybe just describe your new problem here and I'll see if i can help you

Comment: Yes sure, but that sounds like some kind of homework or something. Have you got any code started?

Comment: I'd feel bad just answering it. can you link what you have done here and we can work through it. https://repl.it/languages/python

Comment: when is it due, how much time you got?

Comment: ok what parts do or don't work so far

Comment: Why do you create 20 `questionNumbers` and 20 items in `studentAnswerList` if the problem requires only 10 questions and answers?

Comment: what doesn't work? When I enter 20 letters it prints out the same 20 letters, I get no errors.

Comment: ok, if you can create a chat room at http://chat.stackoverflow.com and invite me there, it would be easier msgs here

Comment: Ok, why does it create 20 questions?

Comment: http://collabedit.com/qgd8u

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try when I get back to desktop

Comment: i did but it shows syntax error for some of them. can you check it

Comment: I don't understand the downvote at all. Let me add a vote.